# Laravel do not run in host

Tags: laravel

I have a laravel project that works well on local hosts. But after the transfer to the host, the following error is given. It runs for a couple of minutes, but after a few times the error is executed.

> is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500

The following errors are found in error_log

```
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Warning:
 include(/home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Stack trace:
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   1. {main}() /home/httprami/public_html/index.php:0
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   2. require_once() /home/httprami/public_html/index.php:38
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct() /home/httprami/public_html/local/bootstrap/app.php:15
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerBaseBindings() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:144
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   5. spl_autoload_call() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   6. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   7. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Warning:  include(/home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Stack trace:
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   1. {main}() /home/httprami/public_html/index.php:0
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   2. require_once() /home/httprami/public_html/index.php:38
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct() /home/httprami/public_html/local/bootstrap/app.php:15
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerBaseBindings() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:144
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   5. spl_autoload_call() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   6. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   7. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Stack trace:
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   1. {main}() /home/httprami/public_html/index.php:0
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   2. require_once() /home/httprami/public_html/index.php:38
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct() /home/httprami/public_html/local/bootstrap/app.php:15
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerBaseBindings() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:144
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   5. spl_autoload_call() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   6. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP   7. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:322
[14-Oct-2018 11:26:33 Asia/Tehran] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem' not found in /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
Stack trace:
#0 /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(144): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerBaseBindings()
#1 /home/httprami/public_html/local/bootstrap/app.php(15): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct('/home/httpramin...')
#2 /home/httprami/public_html/index.php(38): require_once('/home/httpramin...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php on line 175
```

what's the solution?

Comment: I edit the database connection information. The site does not run after saving

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is better and more secure to setup your project behind public_html in share hosting. your laravel public folder has to work as public_html.

as you can see php warning is so clear, it can not find the path:

```
/home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php
```

I can find out you put your project in "local" folder, so did you update index.php in public folder like this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../local/bootstrap/app.php';;
```

to

```
require __DIR__.’/../local/bootstrap/autoload.php’;

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../local/bootstrap/app.php';
```

These 2 following lines in public/index.php line 22 and 36.

for more information about how to deploy laravel project on share hosting, you can check [this link](https://dev.to/asapabedi/deploying-laravel-5-applications-on-shared-hosting-without-the-use-of-ssh--16a6)

Comment: When I print the path, it is the same path as the files

Comment: check out where is true location of `/home/httprami/public_html/local/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php` and verify the path is correct.

Comment: I edit the database connection information. The site does not run after saving

Comment: The problem you have mention above is not related DB, laravel will show you true error message about DB connection.